# how to set the background color in a foreach loop in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have put the "colour.green" in every place within the code and I can't seem to work out how to make the background color of the foreach loop green.

```
struct DictionaryView: View {
    let sectionHeader: String
    let data: [tableContent]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.green
            VStack {
                Section(header: Text(sectionHeader)) {
                List{
                    ForEach(data, id: \.id) { value in
                        HStack {
                            
                            Text(value.label)
                                .fontWeight(.light)
                                .padding(.leading, 20.0)
                                
                                .frame(height: -10.0)
                            Spacer()

                            Text(String(value.data))
                                .fontWeight(.light)
                                .padding(.trailing, 20.0)
                                .frame(height: -10.0)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                        
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting:
[image]

Comment: I tried everything with using backgroundcolor as suggested in the link you provided but this did not work. the listRowBackground constraint is working as per below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this to your HStack inside the ForEach:

```
HStack {
    ...
}   
.listRowBackground(Color.green)
```